# Ruby on rails routing error No route matches [POST] "/index.html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app where all the feature specs pass for signing up however for some reason when I run rails server I keep getting this error

```
Started POST "/index.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-03 22:17:29 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/index.html"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /Users/brozturk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in    `service'
 /Users/brozturk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /Users/brozturk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here are my routes

```
resources :users
root 'users#new'
```

Why would the app try to post index.html?And why would my tests pass but when I run the server it would not work?I had devise installed but then decided not to use it so I did a git reset --hard and continued that way.could that be the issue?How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no route to `/index.html` you can check all available routes with `rake routes`.

Comment: have you deleted `index.html` from the public folder?

Comment: I found the issue sorry for wasting time.I had a pre made design and while adding that to the form i seem to have forgotten a line... <form action="./index.html" method="post"> which causes this issue.